# Stuck on Network Configuration when Installing Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu

Not sure what I'm missing here, but when I am installing Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver) the system can't seem to connect to the router, I keep getting the error message saying that no network has been found - Yet, the system is hard wired into the network and is showing up when I view the admin settings on the router, the server is showing up.

What else can I try to get the system connected so Ubuntu can be installed?

The fact that the system is showing up on the router settings is strange that the server can't seem to find a connection and keeps telling me that DHCP may not be enabled on the router.

Comment: Is it possible that DNS is not being set somehow?

Comment: @JustinPearce Everything is always possible - but how? In this specific scenario, I've had multiple devices hard wired to the identical port previously that have never had a problem connecting directly to the internet. Not sure how I'd even go about debugging this one...any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

> *(many of the following commands will need to run with superuser privileges i.e. execute directly as root or prepend the command with `sudo`)*

- As far as I know Ubuntu 18 uses systemd / networkd for network configuration, start with:

  ```
  networkctl status 
  journalctl -b -u systemd-networkd
  ```

Other basic Linux wired network diagnostics include:

- Check if all expected network interfaces have been detected by the OS and drivers are loaded:

  ```
  lspci                   
  lsusb 
  ifconfig -a 
  dmesg  ( |grep eth )
  ```
- Check if the cables are connected, a link is detected, correct network speeds are negotiated/set:

  ```
  ip link 
  ethtool <interface_name>
  ```
- Check if your OS is configured to automatically start network the interfaces at boot. How that is configured differs between Linux distributions and releases:

  - For Debian based distributions such as Ubuntu:  `/etc/network/interfaces` should have lines starting with keyword `auto`
  - For Red Hat Enterprise Linux derived distributions, RHEL, CentOS, Fedora `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface_name>` should probably contain a keyword `ONBOOT="yes"`
- Those files will also show if the NIC's are configured with a static ip-address or if they should be configured automatically with DHCP.
- Check if any and the **correct** IP-addresses and subnet masks are assigned to your network interface card(s):

  ```
  ip addr
  ifconfig -a
  ```
- Check routing, confirm that a route to 0.0.0.0 and/or a default gateway are present

  ```
  ip route 
  netstat -rn 
  route
  ```
- Can the default gateway be reached:

  ```
  ping <ip-address_of_default_gw>
  ```